# Python SMTP stopped working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, smtp, raspberry-pi

I can't figure out why this code (which used to work and sends me an email with an image attachment) stopped working. I'm running it on a raspberry pi. It seems to run until it gets to the `server.sendmail` line and then gives this error:

```
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Server not connected
```

I am sure that it used to work a few months ago the last time I tried it and I also tried it using a gmail account and smtp.gmail.com instead of my Dreamhost smtp server and got the same error.
The code is:

```
def email(kid):
  fromaddr = "me@email.com"
  toaddr = "me@email.com"
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['From'] = fromaddr
  msg['To'] = toaddr
  msg['Subject'] = kid + " Button Pressed"
  body = kid + " pressed the button"

  msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
  filename = "image.jpg"
  attachment = open("/home/pi/python/image.jpg", "rb")
  part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
  part.set_payload((attachment).read())
  encoders.encode_base64(part)
  part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
  msg.attach(part)
  server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.domain.com', 587)    
  server.starttls()
  server.login(fromaddr, "password")
  text = msg.as_string()
  server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
  server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Gmail (and many others mail services) might be with the security, check this:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

You can change account access for less secure apps or enable the 2 step verification.